# Why should gitlab pages not be served as a subdomain of external_url

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-pages

Excerpt from documentation for setting up GitLab Pages with wildcard DNS entry: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/pages/#wildcard-domains

```
external_url "http://gitlab.example.com" # external_url here is only for reference
pages_external_url "http://pages.example.com" # not a subdomain of external_url
```

`pages_external_url` should not be a subdomain of external_url. But why is that, **since there are no problems doing it that way**.

Comment: Using `pages_nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true` with certificate/key path configured through `pages_nginx['ssl_certificate']` and `pages_nginx['ssl_certificate']` results in the `gitlab.example.com` certificate being used for test-repo.pages.example.com.

Effectivly preventing usage of HTTPS for Pages, except you have the appropiate SANs in the gitlab.example.com certificate. At least these are my findings so far.